# How to get index of selected checkbox or Name of List Item whose checkbox is selected?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a List in which every ListItem has checkbox attached:

```
<List>
    {
      name.map((row,index) =>(
        <ListItem
            key={index}
            leftCheckbox={<Checkbox onCheck={checkBoxSelect.bind(this, index)}/>}
        >
            {name[index]}
        </ListItem>
      ))
    }
</List>
```

Following is the **onCheck** function

```
checkBoxSelect(event, index){
    console.log(index);
}
```

but it's not giving me index, following is the value on console:

```
Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: 
MouseEvent, type: "change", target: input…}
```

how can I get correct index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because order in which you are receiving the parameters, is wrong, parameters that you are passing in `event function` will received first then the `event object`, Use this it will print the correct `index`:

```
checkBoxSelect( index, event){
    console.log(index);
}
```

With your current code, `event` will have the value of `index` and `index` will have the `event Object`, print `event` it will print the correct index value:

```
checkBoxSelect(event, index){
    console.log(event);
}
```